# AWS CDK Lambda says "[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda': No module named 'orjson'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm writing the code on Windows. This is my project structure:

```
my-project/
├─ stack/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ functions/
│  │  │  ├─ lambda.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ my_stack.py
├─ app.py
├─ poetry.lock
├─ pyproject.toml
```

My root stack defines a /package endpoint that takes query parameters:

```
from aws_cdk import Stack, aws_lambda, aws_apigateway as apigw, RemovalPolicy
from constructs import Construct


class MyStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        layer = aws_lambda.LayerVersion(
            self,
            "asset_layer",
            code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset("vendor.zip"),
            description="Dependency layer",
            compatible_runtimes=[aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        )

        lambda_fn = aws_lambda.Function(
            self,
            "lambda_function",
            code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset(path="my_project/stack/src/functions"),
            handler="lambda.handler",
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            layers=[layer],
            environment={
                "POSTGRESQL_NAME": os.environ["POSTGRESQL_NAME"],
                "POSTGRESQL_USER": os.environ["POSTGRESQL_USER"],
                "POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD": os.environ["POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD"],
                "POSTGRESQL_HOST": os.environ["POSTGRESQL_HOST"],
                "POSTGRESQL_PORT": os.environ["POSTGRESQL_PORT"],
            },
        )

        api = apigw.LambdaRestApi(
            self,
            "api",
            handler=lambda_fn,
        )
        package = api.root.add_resource("package")
        package_integration = apigw.LambdaIntegration(lambda_fn)
        package.add_method(
            "GET",
            package_integration,
            request_parameters={
                "method.request.querystring.boxId": True,
                "method.request.querystring.w": True,
                "method.request.querystring.h": True,
                "method.request.querystring.d": True,
            },
            authorization_type=apigw.AuthorizationType.NONE,
            api_key_required=False,
        )
```

My lambda function:

```
import orjson


def handler(event, context):
    print("## ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES")
    print(os.environ)
    print("## EVENT")
    print(event)

    box_id = int(event["queryStringParameters"].get("boxId"))
    width = int(event["queryStringParameters"].get("w"))
    height = int(event["queryStringParameters"].get("h"))
    depth = int(event["queryStringParameters"].get("d"))

    if box_id:
        data = {"width": 1, "height": 2, "depth": 3}
    elif width and height and depth:
        data = {"boxId": 1}
    else:
        data = []

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": orjson.dumps(data),
    }

    return response
```

Because I'm using external dependencies, I used a shell script to export my `pyproject.toml` into a `requirements-poetry.txt` and install my dependencies into the `vendor` directory at the root of the project:

```
poetry export --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt > requirements-poetry.txt
pip install -r requirements-poetry.txt -t ./vendor
```

My `requirements-poetry.txt`:

```
attrs==22.2.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
cattrs==22.2.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
certifi==2022.12.7 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4"
charset-normalizer==3.1.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4"
confuse==2.0.1 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
constructs==10.1.306 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
docker==6.0.1 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
exceptiongroup==1.1.1 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "3.11"
greenlet==2.0.2 ; python_version >= "3.9" and platform_machine == "aarch64" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and platform_machine == "ppc64le" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and platform_machine == "x86_64" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and platform_machine == "amd64" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and platform_machine == "AMD64" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and platform_machine == "win32" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and platform_machine == "WIN32" and python_version < "4.0"
idna==3.4 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4"
importlib-resources==5.12.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
jsii==1.80.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
orjson==3.8.10 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
packaging==23.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
psycopg==3.1.8 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
publication==0.0.3 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
python-dateutil==2.8.2 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
pywin32==306 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0" and sys_platform == "win32"
pyyaml==6.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
requests==2.28.2 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4"
six==1.16.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
sqlalchemy==2.0.9 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
typeguard==2.13.3 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
typing-extensions==4.5.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
tzdata==2023.3 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0" and sys_platform == "win32"
urllib3==1.26.15 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
websocket-client==1.5.1 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
zipp==3.15.0 ; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "3.10"
```

and then make a `vendor.zip` for my layer as you can see in `MyStack`.

However, if I hit my endpoint, it returns 502 and my log says:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda': No module named 'orjson'
```

and it probably means that my lambda function does not recognize the dependency package in the layer.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the contents of `requirements-poetry.txt`?

Comment: Are you sure the code for `MyStack` is correct?  It appears to have the line `environment={` twice.

Comment: @JohnGordon Nice catch, I fat fingered it while writing the question. Sorry about it.

Comment: Is there a way you can display the lambda environment, or possibly the contents of `vendor.zip`, to verify that `orjson` is present?

Comment: @JohnGordon Using AWS CLI `aws lambda list-functions`, I can see the size of my layer at 21.5MB, which is the same as `vendor.zip`. I only have access to the AWS access ID and secret so I can't check anything using the AWS Management Console.

Comment: At what point in the build process does the `vendor` directory become a zip file?

Comment: `runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9` This does not seem to agree with `orjson==3.8.10 ; python_version >= "3.11" and python_version < "4.0"`.  3.9 is not greater than 3.11.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm on Windows so I had to zip it manually using 7zip. The structure is `vendor.zip/<packages>`

Comment: Are the packages located in the root folder of the zip contents, or are they in a subfolder?

Comment: By the way, I don't know anything about AWS CDK, and I know very little about lambdas.  I'm just asking any possible question I can think of!

Comment: Can you show the imports in the lambda function?  I 'm trying to see if `orjson` is the very first import it tries to do (which might then tell us if `orjson` is the _only_ module that is troublesome, or if perhaps the entire `vendor.zip` is suspect.)

Comment: @JohnGordon They're at root. No subfolder. `vendor.zip` will unarchive into a bunch of dependency folders. About the Python version requirement, I updated the requirement to 3.9 just in case, but it still doesn't work. I appreciate your time for going through my question nonetheless!

Comment: Did you re-generate the `vendor.zip` file after updating the requirements?

Comment: @JohnGordon The full code looks like this: https://pastebin.com/YUcw1C4H. Also yes, I did regenerate the `vendor.zip`.

Comment: According to that code, `orjson` is indeed the first non-core module that the code tries to import.  So, maybe the problem is that _nothing_ in `vendor.zip` is being included.  As an experiment, can you update the code to add another import above the one for `orjson` (perhaps for `requests` or `pyyaml`), and see if it complains about that import?

Comment: @JohnGordon I bumped `sqlalchemy` stuff above `orjson` and the error message becomes `[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda': No module named 'sqlalchemy'`.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the real problem is that nothing from `vendor.zip` is found.  The problem is not specific to `orjson`.

Comment: `code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset("vendor.zip")` When that code runs, it's going to look for `vendor.zip` in the current directory (whatever that may be).  Is that correct?  Will the zipfile be in the current directory?  (If it isn't, I would expect it to throw an exception, but maybe not...)

Comment: @JohnGordon It looks for the zip file from the root of the project. But I think that code is safe because if I forgot to make a `vendor.zip` it would yell `RuntimeError: Cannot find asset at path/to/vendor.zip` at me.

Comment: This code `code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset(path="my_project/src/functions")` is that path correct?  According to the diagram at the top of your question, shouldn't it be `my_project/stack/src/functions` instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253068/discussion-between-mint-and-john-gordon).